# Do I need to specify position when adding a new object to an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array called result in Javascript with three elements. Each element contains an objects such as

```
{
  id: 0,
  name: "Page"
}
```

Now I would like to add the object:

```
{
  id: 99,
  name: "All"
}
```

To do this do I need to specify that it's in array position 4 or is there a simpler way I can add it to result?

Comment: Can you show us some of your js code?  Preferably how you are creating these objects

Comment: The objects are converted by another persons script so I am not sure how that is done. All I am passed is the array of simple objects with id and name in each element. I just need to add another element but I am not sure how.

Comment: Just check the answer from @imjared

Comment: Lear about the language you are using! [MDN Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods_of_Array_instances)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add object to array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254050/how-to-add-object-to-array)

Answer (score 5):

If you have an array called 'result', you just need to use the native array method `.push()` to get the object into result. This method will add it to the end of the array.

Eg.

```
result.push(object)
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use the push() method:

```
var myArray = [{
  id: 0,
  name: "Page"
}];

myArray.push({
  id: 99,
  name: "All"
});
```

**Array push method:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to insert an element it is a little trickier. It involves [splicing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) the array like so:

```
var results = ["angel", "clown", "mandarin", "surgeon"];
results.splice(2, 0, "trumpet")
```

This inserts "trumpet" at the 2nd index while pushing "mandarin" and "surgeon" to the right. Note that you can add multiple elements at once but the elements are added as arguments to the splice method and not an array.