# jQuery / JavaScript object, adding to inside function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm struggling with this. I know this is simple when you know how, but I just can't get the hang of it.

I basically want to create an object like this:

```
data = [{
    a: 1
    b: "test"
    c: 32
}, {
    a: 2
    b: "test2"
    c: 55
}, {
    a: 3
    b: "xyz"
    c: 103
}]
```

This is just an example of a larger function, so I don't want to do exactly this, but understanding tis will help me do the larger function.

I would've thought the below would work, but it doesn't quite. I'm guessing it just needs a little tweaking:

```
var data = new Object;

$('.class-name').each(function () {

    var a = $(this).data('a');
    var b = $(this).data('b');
    var c = $(this).data('c');

    data[] = {
        a: a,
        b: b,
        c: c
    }

});
```

I'm struggling with the adding to object thing and also the fact that I'm declaring the object outside the function.

I've tried data.push but I think I'm getting mixed up with arrays and objects.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You have initialized your `data` variable as an `Object` instead of an `array`.  Change `data = new Object` to `data = []` to see if that changes anything.  Then continue to use `data.push`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = [];

//since data is an array
//you can use it's native method `push`
//to add an object or primitive to the next/last index
data.push({
  a: 1,
  b: 'test',
  c: 32
});
```

You can even add multiple objects to the array at once.

```
data.push({ a: 2 b: "test2" c: 55 }, { a: 3 b: "xyz" c: 103 });
```

Or you can create the object separately then add it later.

```
var someObj = {
   a: 123,
   b: 'hello',
   c: 789
};

data.push(someObj);
```

See [related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6254088/292614)

Comment: I've marked this as the answer as it was one of the first and was the one that I followed to get this working. All answers are excellent and Palash Mondal's was probably the most detailed. I can't accept all answers and accepting none isn't helpful, so I've gone with this one. Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You have to d̶e̶c̶l̶a̶r̶e̶  initialize the `data` variable as an array and later "push" news object:

```
var data = [];

$('.class-name').each(function () {

    var a = $(this).data('a');
    var b = $(this).data('b');
    var c = $(this).data('c');

    data.push({
        a: a,
        b: b,
        c: c
    });

});
```

Comment: There are no type declarations in JS. Though you probably mean the right, "*declare variable as*" sounds wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
data = []
data.push({ a: 1, b: 'test', c: 52 })
```

Or directly:

```
data = [{ a: 1, b: 'test', c: 52 }, { a: 2, b: 'test2', c: 53}]
```

Answer (score 1):

To keep things simple, do like this:

```
// Create an empty Array
var data = [];
$('.class-name').each(function () {

    // Get the data attribute values
    var a = $(this).data('a');
    var b = $(this).data('b');
    var c = $(this).data('c');

    // Create an empty Object
    var obj = {};

    // Set the object key-value pairs
    obj['a'] = a;
    obj['b'] = b;
    obj['c'] = c;

    // Push the object to the 'data' array
    data.push(obj);
});

// Check the data array in the console
console.log(data);
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO #1**](http://jsfiddle.net/WURLA/)

But you can always minimize it like:

```
// Create an empty Array
var data = [];
$('.class-name').each(function () {

    // Get the data attribute values
    var a = $(this).data('a');
    var b = $(this).data('b');
    var c = $(this).data('c');

    // Push the object to the 'data' array
    data.push({a:a, b:b, c:c});
});

// Check the data array in the console
console.log(data);
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO #2**](http://jsfiddle.net/WURLA/1/)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> data[] = …
> ```

That's PHP syntax, not JavaScript. You want to use the [Array `push` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) instead. Make data an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) (not a generic object):

```
var data = new Array;
// or simpler with an empty array literal:
var data = [];
```

and then

```
data.push({
    a: a,
    b: b,
    c: c
});
```