# Creating arrays in javascript dynamically

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I'm new in Phonegap app development.

I want to create an array of this type.

```
var myColumnDefs = [
  {id:"id1", name:"name1"},
  {id:"id2", name:"name2"},....  ] ;
```

Please help me how I can do this using javascript.

Because I have to insert data in this coming from webservices.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254050/how-to-add-object-to-array

Comment: Use associative array for this

Comment: @HarishGodara Don't think JS has associative Arrays: `var b=new Array();b["key"]=value;console.log(b.length===0)//=true` What you meant to say is Object.

Comment: @HMR yes I meant object in js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code..

```
    var dataArray = [];
         var length = yourjsonAray.length;
         for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
              var obj = {
                 id: yourjsonAray.keyId[i].id,
                 name: yourjsonAray.keyName[i].name

            };
             dataArray.push(obj);
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Define an array (main array)-

```
var myColumnDefs = new Array();
```

and an object

```
var myObj = new Object();
```

then in your for loop, simply -

```
myObj.id = "ID1";
myObj.name = "Name1";
myColumnDefs.push(myObj);
```

---

**OR**, (better way)

```
function myObj(id, name)
{
  this.name = name;
  this.id = id;
}

myColumnDefs = new array();
myColumnDefs.push(new myObj("ID1", "Name 1"));
```

and so on ..

Comment: No need for the second one (constructor functions), the objects seem to be data objects so object literals would be a lighter solution.