# Dynamically update ng-repeat rows on successful parse.com save

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this `AngularJS` controller

```
app.controller('dataCtrl', function($scope) {

    function getData() {
        var myData = Parse.Object.extend('myData');

        var query = new Parse.Query(myData);

        query.find({
            success: function(results) {
                $scope.$apply(function() {
                    $scope.resultData = results.map(function(obj) {
                        return {
                            startDate: obj.get('StartDate'),
                            endDate: obj.get('EndDate'),
                            investment: obj.get('Investment'),
                            format: obj.get('Format'),
                            partner: obj.get('Partner'),
                            purpose: obj.get('Purpose')
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }

    getData();

    $scope.refreshData = function() { 
        getData();
    }

    $scope.submit = function() { {

        var myData = Parse.Object.extend('myData');
        var formData = new myData();

        formData.save({
            StartDate:  $scope.startDate,
            EndDate:    $scope.endDate,
            Investment: parseInt($scope.investment),
            Format:     $scope.format,
            Partner:    $scope.partner,
            Purpose:    $scope.purpose
        }, {
            success: function(formData) {
                console.log('Success');
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Along with `<form ng-submit="submit()">`

and

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in resultData">
    <td>{{x.startDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>
    <td>{{x.endDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>
    <td>{{x.investment}}</td>
    <td>{{x.format}}</td>
    <td>{{x.partner}}</td>
    <td>{{x.purpose}}</td>
</tr>
```

I can successfully reload new data manually with a button calling the `refreshData()` function. However I would like the view to update the `ng-repeat` with the newly created row on a successful form submission. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can save the data and on save you will get response object. you have to  put that response object in model resultData

your response data will come under formData.

```
success: function(formData) {
    $scope.resultData=formData;
    console.log('Success');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add the data object in your ng-repeat list when you get success response from your api. it will render the newly added object in your ng-repeat list.

for adding the added object at the top :

```
jQuery.merge([existed list], {new object});
```

it will serve your purpose.

Put anything into an array using Array.push().

```
var a=[], b={};
a.push(b);    
// a[0] === b;
```

Extra information on Arrays

**Add more than one item at a time**

```
var x = ['a'];
x.push('b', 'c');
// x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

**Add items to the beginning of an array**

```
var x = ['c', 'd'];
x.unshift('a', 'b');
// x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

**Add the contents of one array to another**

```
var x = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var y = ['d', 'e', 'f'];
x.push.apply(x, y);
// x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
// y = ['d', 'e', 'f']  (remains unchanged)
```

**Create a new array from the contents of two arrays**

```
var x = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var y = ['d', 'e', 'f'];
var z = x.concat(y);
// x = ['a', 'b', 'c']  (remains unchanged)
// y = ['d', 'e', 'f']  (remains unchanged)
// z = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

hope it will help.

Reference from : [How to add an object to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254050/how-to-add-an-object-into-an-array)

Comment: Hello and thank's. Can you please elaborate your answer? Also I am not using jQuery for this project.

Answer (score 0):

You have to append new row object to `resultData`.

It seems object `keys` are not matched between AngularJS Scope Object Model and Parse Object Model. Creating Adaptor method will make this task easier.

```
function createMyDataObjectFromParseObject(parseObject){
    return {
        startDate: parseObject.get('StartDate'),
        endDate: parseObject.get('EndDate'),
        investment: parseObject.get('Investment'),
        format: parseObject.get('Format'),
        partner: parseObject.get('Partner'),
        purpose: parseObject.get('Purpose')

    };
}
```

Use it in both success method,

Data Fetching Call should be like this,

```
query.find({
        success: function(results) {
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                $scope.resultData = results.map(function(obj) {
                    return createMyDataObjectFromParseObject(obj);
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

New Row Creation should be like this,

```
$scope.submit = function() { {

    var myData = Parse.Object.extend('myData');
    var formData = new myData();

    formData.save({
        StartDate:  $scope.startDate,
        EndDate:    $scope.endDate,
        Investment: parseInt($scope.investment),
        Format:     $scope.format,
        Partner:    $scope.partner,
        Purpose:    $scope.purpose
    }, {
        success: function(newParseObject) {
            var newObj = createMyDataObjectFromParseObject(newParseObject);
            $scope.resultData.push(newObj)
        }
    })
}
```