# How do you push a specified number of objects to an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm pretty new to javascript but I'm trying to push a specified number of objects to an array using the following code. When I check the console I see only one object is pushed to the array. What should I be doing differently? Thanks!

```
var albums = {};

function collection(numberOfAlbums) {
    array = [];
    array.push(albums);
    return array;

};

console.log(collection(12));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add an object into an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254050/how-to-add-an-object-into-an-array)

Comment: staxwell: Have you learned about `for` loops yet? If not, then the only thing you're probably needing is to read a beginner's tutorial.

Comment: Use `for-loop` to add `n` number of items..`var albums = {};

    function collection(numberOfAlbums) {
      var array = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < numberOfAlbums; i++) {
        array.push(albums);
      }
      return array;
    };

    console.log(collection(12));`

Comment: You can use concat() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Answer (score 1):

From your code:

```
array.push(albums);
```

would add *the same object* each time (assuming you had added a loop) which isn't what you want.

This will add *a new empty object* for each iteration of `numberOfAlbums`:

```
function collection(numberOfAlbums) {
  for (var array = [], i = 0; i < numberOfAlbums; i++) {
    array.push({});
  }
  return array;
};
```

Here's another way using `map`. `Array.apply` trick [from here](http://www.2ality.com/2013/11/initializing-arrays.html).

```
function collection(numberOfAlbums) {
  var arr = Array.apply(null, Array(numberOfAlbums));
  return arr.map(function (el) { return {}; });
};
```

Answer (score -2):

I could give you the code but that is not learning. So here are the steps:

1. use numberOfAlbums as an argument in a function.
2. create an empty array.
3. use numberOfAlbums in for-loops in that for-loops push albums. ==array.push(albums)== do not use {}curly brackets around albums.
4. return the array.