# Bindings not updated after array size change in UI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I need to enable or disable a button based on the bound array size.

```
<mvc:View
  xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
  height="100%"
  controllerName="test.controller.expbind">
  <Button text="Need to Enable" enabled="{= ${/listOfData}.length > 0 }"/>
  <List headerText="Data" items="{/listOfData}">
    <StandardListItem title="{Name}" />
  </List>
  <Button text="AddSomeData" press=".onPress" />
</mvc:View>
```

```js
onInit: function() {
  this.viewModel = new JSONModel({
    listOfData: []
  });
  this.getView().setModel(this.viewModel);
},

onPress: function() {
  var existingdata = this.viewModel.getProperty('/listOfData');
  existingdata.push({ Name:"New" });
  this.viewModel.setProperty('/listOfData', existingdata);
},
```

After adding the data, the "Need to Enable"-button has to be enabled, but its not happening.

Is there ayny issue with my expression binding?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a New Item to a Table / List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48222553/add-a-new-item-to-a-table-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since XMLView expression binding is calculated during pre-processing, it's not being recalculated upon updating the model directly.

You can avoid this behavior by using a formatter function, or update the model with a forced refresh of the bindings after you have updated your model:

```
this.viewModel.refresh(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **`.concat`**<sup>[api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)</sup> instead.

```js
const myArray = myClientModel.getProperty('/data');
// instead of myArray.push({/*...*/});
const myNewArray = myArray.concat({/*...*/}); // myNewArray !== myArray
myClientModel.setProperty('/data', /*instead of the old reference:*/myNewArray);
```

`.push` should be avoided since it manipulates the original array causing [side-effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254050/how-to-add-an-object-to-an-array/42428064#comment84142570_42428064). The real reason why it didn't work in your case, however, was because the reference passed to `setProperty` was identical to the old reference (internally [compared with `===` within `deepEqual()`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/eceb75d3282e5731fd2424fd15514f8fe5a6bb4d/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/base/util/deepEqual.js#L43)). Hence, UI5 sees no change and doesn't notify any listeners.

`model.refresh(true)` unnecessarily forces all bindings (incl. aggregation bindings) and all listeners to re-calculate everything.

**`.concat`** on the other hand, creates a **new** reference. UI5 notifies then only those listeners that care about the change.