# Add multiple objects into an array using JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Need to create a specific array of objects with the given objects.
Now I have used object of assign.

Here is

```
var str = [{componentName: "Transformer", type: "PUB", beanName: "TransformerExtractor", state: "enabled", config: {"test":"test"}},{componentName: "DBEE", type: "PUBSUB", beanName: "DBEErExtractor", state: "enabled", config: {"test":"test"}}];

var A1 = [];

var B1 = [];

finalOutput = [];

for(i=0;i<str.length;i++){

    alert(str.length);

    var output = {};

    output.flowId = "Flow1234";

    output.flowAlias = "Flow1234";

    output.description = "Flow1234";

    output.state = "Enabled";

    A1.push(output);

    alert (A1);

    B1.push(str[i]);

    alert (B1);

    finalOutput = [A1, B1].map(o => Object.assign({}, A1, o));
}

alert (finalOutput);

return finalOutput;
```

Could you please tell me how do I get my expected result like [{A1,B1(from first set of variable str),{A1,B1(from 2nd set of variable str)]

Comment: Please create a minimal reproducible example, your code is far from minimal and that makes it hard to read.

Comment: [How to push object into array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40250139/push-object-into-array/40251425)

Comment: Are you trying to achieve `A1+B1` and `A1+C1 ` ?

Comment: push-object is not working for getting my expected result

Comment: Okay i see, this might be helpful [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: see the answer by nina, it demonstrates the use of it. it will also overwrite the duplicate keys.

Comment: Yes Kratos and using Nina's solution I am getiing like below {"str1":{"0":"componentName":"Transformation","type":"PUBSUB","beanName":"transformer","state":"enabled","config":"{\n\"area\": \"testVM\",\n\"pubTo\": \"trf_p\",\n\"subFrom\": \"db_p\",\n\"project\": \"testVM\",\n\"section\": \"FT\"\n}"},"1":"componentName":"testComponent","type":"PUB","beanName":"testComponent","state":"enabled","config":"{\"testComponent\":\"testComponent\"}"},"flowId":"ABC100","flowAlias":"","description":"","state":"enabled","creationDate":""}}

Comment: Now I want to avoid 0 and 1. Also the common section need to add to each of that part

Comment: Hi Kratos, I have edited my code by using Object Assign, yet still fighting to get desired data. Could you please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the data from the last edit, you could define a template object for the data you like to add to a new object along to the objects of the array.

```js
var data = [{ componentName: "Transformer", type: "PUB", beanName: "TransformerExtractor", state: "enabled", config: { test: "test" } },{ componentName: "DBEE", type: "PUBSUB", beanName: "DBEErExtractor", state: "enabled", config: { test: "test" } }],
    template = { flowId: "Flow1234", flowAlias: "Flow1234", description: "Flow1234", state: "Enabled" },
    result = data.map(o => Object.assign({}, template, o));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks Nina for your solution. Although using your idea I am getting like below
{"str1":[{"0":"flowId":"ABC100","flowAlias":"","description":"","state":"enabled","creationDate":""},"1":"flowId":"ABC100","flowAlias":"","description":"","state":"enabled","creationDate":""}},{"0":"componentName":"Transformation","type":"PUBSUB","beanName":"transformer","state":"enabled","config":"{\n\"project\": \"testVM\",\n\"section\": \"FT\"\n}"},"1":"componentName":"testComponent","type":"PUB","beanName":"testComponent","state":"enabled","config":"{\"testComponent\":\"testComponent\"}"}}]}

Comment: it looks, you have different data, then posted.

Comment: Sorry again. Still  I am fighting. I have edited my code here https://jsfiddle.net/e03onuxk/

Comment: it's a complete different data set. please post what you have and what you want.

Comment: Thanks Nina. This is my code https://jsfiddle.net/e03onuxk/4/  and expected result will be like above.

Comment: you try to add data to an object which you already have. `A1` to `A1`, which is confusing.

Comment: According to my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/e03onuxk/5/  I want to get {A1,One set of B1},{A1,another set of B1} and so on.

Comment: please ask a new question with raw data, your try and the wanted result.

Comment: Could you please give  me a hint here since my ask question limit has been expired for this month :(

Comment: alternatively, you could append this question with the data, you have and the wanted result out of it. actually it's quite unclear, **why** you want to get a different result than posted from me and others.

Comment: Hi Nina, I have edited my code by using Object Assign, yet still fighting to get desired data.

Comment: you want to add `flowId`, `flow...`, and so on to every object of `str`?

Comment: Yesss Nina but I could not make it done :(

Comment: please have a look.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nina. This is working for me and today I have learnt a new in JS. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You could use lodash if you just want merge them

```
data = _.merge(A1, B1)
```

Comment: getting below error
Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined

Comment: you need to add **lodash** to your project

Comment: Here I can't use this. I have edited my code here https://jsfiddle.net/e03onuxk/