# Can't push to array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I get an error when I run this code:

```
var array = [];

array.push(["one"]:[1,2,3]);
array.push(["two"]:[4,5,6]);
```

I want my array to look like this in the end:
`{"one": [1,2,3], "two": [4,5,6]};`

I don't know how to fix this error, I want to use `push`.

Comment: What you describe as desired result is not an array, it's an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An associative array in JavaScript is an object, so you can't use array.push as that's not valid there. You'd just want: `array["one"] = [1,2,3]`

Answer (score 0):

You should be opting for something like below. Using push, you will not achieve your desired output.

```
let obj = {};

const item1 = {
  ["one"]: [1, 2, 3]
}
const item2 = {
  ["two"]: [4, 5, 6]
}

obj = {
  ...obj,
  ...item1,
  ...item2
}
```

The reason you got the error is because you are missing object wrapper notation in your push `{}`

```
array.push({["one"]:[1,2,3]});
array.push({["two"]:[4,5,6]});
```

but as said, this will not give the desired output: `{"one": [1,2,3], "two": [4,5,6]};`

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = {};

array.one = [123, 123];
array.two = [123, 123];

console.log(array)
```

output
{
one: [
123,
123
],
two: [
123,
123
]
}

Comment: change your `var array = [];` to `var array = {};`

Answer (score 0):

You must first create the object, assign values into the object, then push it into the array. Refer to this post for more information.
[push object into array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40250139/push-object-into-array)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't have Associative Arrays like other languages, but it have Objects, that is similar.

```
var object = {};

object.one = [1,2,3];

// or if the key name comes from a variable:

var key = "two";

object[key] = [4,5,6];
```

Answer (score -1):

"one" is an object not an array. remove the parenthesis from there. See below code:

```
array.push({"one":[1,2,3]});
array.push({"two":[4,5,6]});
```

Comment: I want my array to look like this in the end: {"one": [1,2,3], "two": [4,5,6]}; does not equal to your solution