# Javascript how to loop over the object to pick up selected items

Tags: javascript

I want to loop over the `data` object and pick two items i.e. `year` and `revenue` from it and put it into a new object

```
var data [{"year": 2014, "revenue": 20000, "costs": 10000, "hours": 50}, {"year": 2015, "revenue": 30000, "costs": 20000, "hours": 54}, {"year": 2016, "revenue": 30000, "costs": 10000, "hours": 40}]

var pickedData = {};

data.forEach(output)

function output(d) {
     Object.assign({}, pickedData.Year = d.year),
     Object.assign({}, pickedData.Revenue = d.revenue)
}
```

The code works but assign only the last item in `data` to the new object `pickedData` which means it is looping it over but not assigning value to the object everytime it goes through. How can I have output like this:

```
console.log(pickedData)
 [{Year: 2014, Revenue: 20000}, {Year: 2015, Revenue: 30000}, {Year: 2016, Revenue: 30000}]
```

Comment: Why do you use `Object.assign` and why in this way? Take a look at [its documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). Pushing objects inside your `pickedData` object can easily be done with `Array.push` as explained here: [How to add an object to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254050/how-to-add-an-object-to-an-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var pickedData = data.map(item => {
  return {
    Year: item.year,
    Revenue: item.revenue
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map()` method instead and return new array as result.

```js
var data = [{"year": 2014, "revenue": 20000, "costs": 10000, "hours": 50}, {"year": 2015, "revenue": 30000, "costs": 20000, "hours": 54}, {"year": 2016, "revenue": 30000, "costs": 10000, "hours": 40}]

var result = data.map(({year, revenue}) => ({year, revenue}));
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [{"year": 2014, "revenue": 20000, "costs": 10000, "hours": 50}, {"year": 2015, "revenue": 30000, "costs": 20000, "hours": 54}, {"year": 2016, "revenue": 30000, "costs": 10000, "hours": 40}];

var pickedDate = data.map(function(v,i,a){
  var retObj={};
  if(v.year) retObj.year = v.year;
  if(v.revenue != undefined) retObj.revenue=v.revenue;
  return retObj;
})

console.log(pickedDate);
```