# How can i append in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax

First off i'll state the obvious, i'm new to javascript,html, and web development tools.

```
var labels = {{ labels|tojson|safe }};
```

using console.log i was able to see the content of labels `console.log(JSON.stringify(labels));`
output:

```
[
    {"id":"1","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4802","xMin":"4770","yMax":"156","yMin":"141"},
    {"id":"2","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4895","xMin":"4810","yMax":"157","yMin":"141"},
    {"id":"3","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4923","xMin":"4903","yMax":"156","yMin":"145"},
    {"id":"4","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4956","xMin":"4931","yMax":"156","yMin":"145"}
]
```

It's clearly a list of dictionaries, so far so good, now there is new elements i want to append as it runs and WITHOUT REFRESHING THE PAGE Manually, it should auto update, so since i have some experience with python, i quickly thought about appending, something like that :

```
labels.append({"id":labels.length + 1, 
               "name":"",
               "xMin":xMin,
               "xMax":xMax,
               "yMin":yMin,
               "yMax":yMax
              })
```

but it isn't working, how can i append that line?

Comment: try labels.push()

Comment: Are you talking about add an object to an array? If yes, you can easily find the answer on google or making some search here in S.O

Comment: Yes adding an object to a list and that object happens to be a dictionary in my case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add an object to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254050/how-to-add-an-object-to-an-array)

Comment: Are you consuming a REST API for getting the JSON payload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`labels` is a array type as it has

```
[{"id":"1","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4802","xMin":"4770","yMax":"156","yMin":"141"},{"id":"2","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4895","xMin":"4810","yMax":"157","yMin":"141"},{"id":"3","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4923","xMin":"4903","yMax":"156","yMin":"145"},{"id":"4","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4956","xMin":"4931","yMax":"156","yMin":"145"}]
```

So you need to use `labels.push(obj)` to add new object in the `labels` instead of `append()`

```js
var labels = [{"id":"1","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4802","xMin":"4770","yMax":"156","yMin":"141"},{"id":"2","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4895","xMin":"4810","yMax":"157","yMin":"141"},{"id":"3","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4923","xMin":"4903","yMax":"156","yMin":"145"},{"id":"4","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4956","xMin":"4931","yMax":"156","yMin":"145"}]

var xMin = 1, xMax = 5, yMin = 3, yMax = 8;

labels.push({"id":labels.length + 1, "name":"", "xMin": xMin, "xMax":xMax, "yMin":yMin, "yMax":yMax});

console.log(labels);
```

Answer (score 2):

`Array.prototype.append()` does not exist. You need to use `Array.prototype.push()` if you want to add to it:

Like this:

```js
var labels = [{"id":"1","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4802","xMin":"4770","yMax":"156","yMin":"141"},{"id":"2","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4895","xMin":"4810","yMax":"157","yMin":"141"},{"id":"3","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4923","xMin":"4903","yMax":"156","yMin":"145"},{"id":"4","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4956","xMin":"4931","yMax":"156","yMin":"145"}];

console.log(labels);


labels.push({"id":labels.length + 1, "name":"name", "xMin":'xMin', "xMax":'xMax', "yMin":'yMin', "yMax":'yMax'});

console.log(labels);
```